# Как в Bootstrap разместить ссылки навбара справа?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, стандартно в бутстрапе ссылки в выпадающем меню при размере монитора меньше 767px расположены слева. Подскажите как разместить их справа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Справа от Minima? Или выровнять по правому краю, оставив их в выпадающем меню?

Comment: Выровнять по правому краю, оставив в выпадающем меню

Comment: Ответил и так и так :) на всякий случай, для тех, кто будет натыкаться на вопрос через гугл.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите выровнять ссылки по правому краю - используйте `text-align`:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Если вы хотите разместить ссылки правее Minima в один ряд, я бы рекомендовал не делать этого. Ссылки размещаются в выпадающем списке для того, чтобы нормально отображаться на узких экранах вплоть до смартфонов. И разместив их правее Minima - вы рискуете получить поехавшую верстку на смартфонах.

Вместо этого лучше подкорректируйте `grid-float-breakpoint`, уменьшите до комфортного вам значения. Это можно сделать в LESS или SASS версии бутстрапа, изменив переменную. Либо [на сайте бутстрапа](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), скачав после корректировки особую его CSS-сборку.

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav>li {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-right" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```